# Locating starting and ending points inside of strings python

Tags: python, list, indexing, nested-lists

In a variable called main, which is a list, there are multiple strings, sentences under each index, in each row. Inside of those strings common words occur.

The idea is to locate those commonly occuring words in my case ('sentences that' -beginning of the sentence) and 'end point' as the ending of the sentence. The ultimate goal is to get the information starting from the ('sentences that') row all the way till 'end point" words are encountered and put it all in a list.

Code:

```
sentence1 = "some \n   empty  sentences that \n Im looking for to find \n end \n end point \n maybe"
sentence2 = "everytime \n,\n sentences that \n come \n start to \n end point "
main = [sentence1,sentence2]
```

OUTPUT sentence1:

```
some 
   empty  sentences that 
 Im looking for to find 
 end 
 end point 
 maybe

#OUTPUT sentence2:

everytime 
,
 sentences that 
 come 
 start to 
 end point
```

Attempt:

```
#code

sentence1 = "some \n   empty  sentences that \n Im looking for to find \n end \n end point \n maybe"
sentence2 = "everytime \n,\n sentences that \n come \n start to \n end point "
main = [sentence1,sentence2]


start = 'sentences that'
end = 'end point'
for i,e in enumerate(main):
    for j in e:
        if start in e:
           print(j.find(start))
        if end in e:
            print(j.find(end))
```

output:

```
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

Manual showcase - Desired output

```
eventual manual code output:
print( main[0][3:9]) 
print( main[1][3:7]) 


# DESIRED OUTPUT:
# main[0] 

   empty  sentences that 
 Im looking for to find 
 end 
 end point 

# main[1]: 

 sentences that 
 come 
 start to 
 end point
```

For the sentence1: some, maybe - words are excluded
For the sentence2: everytime  and comma (,) - are excluded

Comment: Do you have any questions or comments on the proposal below?

Comment: @rawrex the suggestion given is almost the same as mine except that you used index(), which is okay because that's the idea. however, I've corrected the post to make it more clear if it wasn't already. The idea is to slice with the starting and ending points when certain word is detected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the question is, but if you want to log where in the list you found an element which contains the start or the end point, you could print it this way:

```
sentence1 = ['some','   ','empty','sentences that ,', 'Im looking for','to find','end ',"",'end point',"maybe"]
for i, word in enumerate(sentence1 ):
    if start in word:
        print(i)
    if end in word:
        print(i)
```

Maybe to gather the start numbers:

```
start_indexes = [ i for i, word in enumerate(sentence1 ) if start in word ]
end_indexes = [ i for i, word in enumerate(sentence1 ) if end in word ]
```

Then if you can make sure, that there is no duplicate `start`s adjacent to each other without having an `end` between them, you can merge the lists, and each pair will conatin a slice.
This could be made as well this way:

```
indexes = [ i for i, word in enumerate(sentence1 ) if start in word or end in word ]


for i in range(len(indexes/2)):
    print( sentence1 [ indexes[i*2] : indexes[i*2 + 1] + 1] )
```

I hope I understood your question

Comment: Mistake that I've made in the post is that the "sentence1" and "sentence2" was a string not a list. So sentence1 sentence2 (strings)  are together inside of a list but it's not a nested list. So probably then I would have to create a nested list out of them in order to be able to slice.. (I've updated the post)